# Getting columns to work?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have 4 columns whilst trying to get the image to sit above the 'about' section.

It should read:

Column 1:
Img and
About Us

Column 2:
Contact

Column 3:
News 1

Column 4: News 2

But as you can see from [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63f62/) it's not working. Code below.

```
<section id="about">
<div id="profile" class="column">
<div class="thumb"><img width="240" height="350" src="http://www.lottanieminen.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/lottanieminen_NEWS_portrait.jpg" alt="Lotta Nieminen"/>
</div>
</div>
<div id="about-page" class="column">
<h2>About Us</h2>
Lotta Nieminen is an illustrator, graphic designer and art director from Helsinki, Finland. She has studied graphic design and illustration at the University of Art and Design Helsinki and the Rhode Island School of Design, and has worked as a freelancer in both fields since 2006. After working for fashion magazine Trendi, Pentagram Design and RoAndCo Studio, 
</div>
<div id="contacts" class="column">
<h2>Contact</h2>
Lotta Nieminen is an illustrator, graphic designer and art director from Helsinki, Finland. She has studied graphic design and illustration at the University of Art and Design Helsinki and the Rhode Island School of Design, and has worked as a freelancer in both fields since 2006. After working for fashion magazine Trendi, Pentagram Design and RoAndCo Studio, Lotta now runs her own New York-based studio.
</div>
</section>
<section id="news">
<div class="news--1 column clearfix">
<h2>News 1</h2>
Lotta Nieminen is an illustrator, graphic designer and art director from Helsinki, Finland. She has studied graphic design and illustration at the University of Art and Design Helsinki and the Rhode Island School of Design, and has worked as a freelancer in both fields since 2006. After working for fashion magazine Trendi, Pentagram Design and RoAndCo Studio, Lotta now runs her own New York-based studio.
</div>
<div class="news--2 column clearfix">
<h2>News 2</h2>
Lotta Nieminen is an illustrator, graphic designer and art director from Helsinki, Finland. She has studied graphic design and illustration at the University of Art and Design Helsinki and the Rhode Island School of Design, and has worked as a freelancer in both fields since 2006. After working for fashion magazine Trendi, Pentagram Design and RoAndCo Studio, Lotta now runs her own New York-based studio.
</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
/* !Meta */
html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,code,del,dfn,em,img,q,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td { list-style-type:none; color:inherit; text-decoration:none; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; font-weight:inherit; font-style:inherit; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; outline:none; border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; }
.clearfix:after { content:"."; display:block; clear:both; visibility:hidden; line-height:0; height:0; }
.clearfix { display:inline-block; }
html[xmlns] .clearfix { display:block; }
* html .clearfix { height:1%; }

/* !Basics  */
html { width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; }
body { width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; }
body { color: #131313; font-family: Caslon540BT-Regular; font-size:13px; }


.column {width: 42%; margin-left: 4%; margin-right: 4%; float:left; }
.thumb img {width:100%!important; height:auto!important; margin-bottom:30px; }
#news {float: right; width: 50%;}
#about {padding-bottom: 60px; float:left; display:inline-block; width: 50%;}
#profile {float: left; clear: left;}
#contacts {float:left;}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/63f62/1/)

Comment: Not really. Trying to build similar columns to this: http://www.lottanieminen.com/ (click about)

Comment: Please explain further as there is a large gap between what you have and what you want compared to the question you asked. Do you want images in all columns? Do you want the same navigation menu as the given site?

Comment: I want the columns to look similar, images in the first, third and fourth. But I don't want the navigation to look the same.

Comment: I notice you have literally ripped all of the sample code from her page but have left out quite a lot of it, which is why it isn't displaying correctly. You should go to the page and manually inspect each element (`F12`) to see their styles. It will save time over copying the entire code and removing the unnecessary bits, which I would be strongly against ethically anyway.

Comment: I know. This is more of me learning than actually doing a live project. I will do as you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated JsFiddle solution to your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/datechogeek/BTw25/

If you want `image` and `about us` content in `column1` for this you have to place them in the same `div` as i did it on my fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:  lottanieminen.com (click about)

Comment: here is the updated fiddle for the code you are looking for
[http://jsfiddle.net/datechogeek/BTw25/2/]

Comment: Updated Js Fiddle for the answer you are looking for [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/datechogeek/BTw25/2/)